# Do I need dependencies after webpack bundled my code

Tags: npm, webpack, dependencies, babeljs

When webpack bundles the node_modules my project needs, do I still need dependencies or could I list everything to devDependencies?

I have created a react component library and have published it to npm. The only peerDependencies I've listed are `react` and `react-dom`, because, well, you'll need them when using my library. At first I set up my project like I normally would, stuff like `babel`, `eslint`, `css-loader` listed in the devDependencies, and stuff I actually use in my code, like `prop-types`, `classnames`, `react-slick`, listed as dependencies.

I then use webpack with babel to create one `main.js` with the module imports included

When someone on my team tries to use my library npm will give some errors 'Peer dependencies unmet' with stuff like `webpack`, `eslint` & `@babel/core`. So I'm guessing these are some peer dependencies from my dependencies? *(that's a little side question)*

That got me thinking, do I even need dependencies at all? Since webpack bundles everything and I only use my `main.js`, shouldn't everything be a devDependency?

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies are those that your project needs to run, like a library that provides functions that you call from your code.
Dev dependencies are dependencies you only need during development or releasing, like compilers that take your code and compile it into javascript, test frameworks or documentation generators.

Comment: That I understand. Doesn't answer my question at all however